# Wordpress wp_redirect Function Error

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am getting the following error when using wp_redirect function;

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\xx\wp-includes\formatting.php:5103) in C:\xampp\htdocs\xx\wp-includes\pluggable.php on line 1216

Code;

```
     <?php

        if (preg_match('#' . basename(__FILE__) . '#', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])){
            die('You are not allowed to call this page directly.');
        }

        if(!is_admin ()){ exit(); }

        $op = $_GET['op'];
        $id = $_GET['id'];

    if($op=="delete" and $id)
      {
         global $wpdb;

          if($wpdb->delete('my_table',array('id'=>$id)))
             {

               if(wp_redirect(admin_url('admin.php?my_plugin?result=successful'))){
                    exit();
             }
     }
     else
      {
        if(wp_redirect(admin_url('admin.php?my_plugin?result=unsuccessful'))){
                    exit();
      }
    }
 }

?>
```

WP Version : 4.9.1

How can I fix? Thanks.

Comment: did you print or echo above the redirect?

Comment: Yes, I did. When I tried the normal header command too, I got the same error.

Comment: do not print anything above redirect

Comment: I've tried. I'm getting the same error.

Comment: can you post your full code?

Comment: I updated the post. When I try this, I get the same mistake.

Comment: you are using this code in page or functions.php file?

Comment: It's a page. I'm not calling from a function. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Please check following 2 points in code.

1) Check an extra space after closing the **php ?>** tag,- ttp://prntscr.com/hxh3i7 , if this is found then remove it.

2) Check if you're sending data to the browser before calling wp_redirect(), if yes then move your code before send anything.

Please share your whole code if following 2 points won;t help you.

Comment: I've already tried the methods. These are all the codes. Thank you for help.